# Spring boot declarative transaction management

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am working on an application written in `Spring-Boot` and `JPA`, the application has started from scratch. So I am thinking of introducing transaction management in it. There is entity and service layer in the application. Right now what I am thinking is that to go with Spring declarative transaction management. So, I have decided to put the `@Transaction` annotation on the top of the service layer itself as shown below, please advise is there any best approach to do the same also please make a note that I am using spring-boot-starter-data-jpa dependency itself

```
@Transactional
public class UserService {

}
```

Comment: That's a common way to do it; you're on the right path.

Comment: @Jesper Please add your comment as the answer. I'm tired of looking at already answered questions in comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question is a bit too general, but your way of thinking is one of the standard and acceptable ways to work with declarative transaction management. I usually though do it per service method. This way you can specify if transaction is read only and some other parameters per particular service method which I think is more flexible.

Answer (score 0):

It's not quite clear what your question is; do you just want someone to tell you that your approach is valid?

When you design a Spring application with a layered architecture, it is common to have the transaction boundaries on the service layer. The service layer then uses Spring Data repositories (which are in the data access layer). Your approach, where you use `@Transaction` annotations on the service layer, is a common way of doing this. So you are on the right track.